# Reset button does not reset text area

Tags: php, html, mysql, function, reset

Hope you can help me with this. I have a html form with multiple text fields and two text areas.I use php for retrieving data from mysql database I've created a function initvars():

```
function initVars() {
 //declaring variables
 global $id,$ccode,$lno,$ldate,$apply_to,$type,$lexpiry,$smexpiry,$status,
     $version,$patch,$hname,$hostid,$plat,$cpus,$company,$country,$var,
$contact, $email,$po,$inv, $invdate,$notes,  $find, $reset,  $next, $previous;

$id="";
$lno = "";
$ldate="";
$apply_to="";
$type="";
$find = "";
$reset="";
$next="";
$previous="";
$apply_to="";
$lexpiry="";
$smexpiry="";
$status="";
$version="";
$patch="";
$hname="";
$hostid="";
$plat="";
$cpus="";
$company="";
$ccode = "";
$country="";
$var="";
$contact="";
$email="";
$po="";
$inv="";
$invdate="";
$notes="";
$history="";
$message ="";
$resultOffset=0;

}
```

Then Im calling that function under my reset button:

```
     if ($reset){

initVars();
  }
```

Ant thats a piece of html for my text area:

```
  <tr><td>
  <h3>History</h3>
  <textarea name="history"  cols="100" rows="5" wrap="virtual"><?php echo 
   $history;?></textarea>
   </td></tr>
```

And my reset button:

```
  <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/></td></tr></table>
```

For some unknown for me reason every time I hit reset button all text fields and one text area are cleared but just this "history" text area still holds retrieved data. Did anyone have similar problem or anyone know how to fix it. Any advise highly appreciated. I can paste more code if needed. Thank you all

Comment: Uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhmmmmmmm `<input type="reset">`????

Comment: <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>

Comment: I see register_globals here :)

Comment: Well I did change it to <input type="reset"> before cos thought that might be the reason but then none of the fields are being reseted.So it makes no sense to me :(

Comment: @PeeHaa I know, I had to check too. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.reset.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

function initVars() {
 //declaring variables
 global $id,$ccode,$lno,$ldate,$apply_to,$type,$lexpiry,$smexpiry,$status,
     $version,$patch,$hname,$hostid,$plat,$cpus,$company,$country,$var,
$contact, $email,$po,$inv, $invdate,$notes,$history, $find, $reset,  $next, $previous;

$id="";
$lno = "";
$ldate="";
$apply_to="";
$type="";
$find = "";
$reset="";
$next="";
$previous="";
$apply_to="";
$lexpiry="";
$smexpiry="";
$status="";
$version="";
$patch="";
$hname="";
$hostid="";
$plat="";
$cpus="";
$company="";
$ccode = "";
$country="";
$var="";
$contact="";
$email="";
$po="";
$inv="";
$invdate="";
$notes="";
$history="";
$message ="";
$resultOffset=0;

}

Comment: Zalonis, that did work.I just cant see the difference? Amazing :) But still input type has to be set to "submit" not "reset" Thanks a mill

Comment: I am happy for that. the different is that you need to add the variable $history in global variables.

Comment: If you want just a function to reset your html form, you can use a javascript function. It works without submit and page reload.

Comment: Ok cheers, might try that in the future. Still cant believe i didnt declare it. What a shame

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

Comment: thats what it is now <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/> but as I said doesn't work for any of the fields